# My Simple Background Subtraction Algorithm does not work

Tags: c++, opencv

I use OpenCV 2.4.9 , Visual Studio 2013.

I develop a program which extract the object from the background. The background shows as black and the object show as it's original color.
I receive an input via Notebook camera.

Here is my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    namedWindow("Background Subtraction");
    VideoCapture capture(0); // Open the default camera
    if (!capture.isOpened())  // Check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat bg_frame;   // Capture 1st frame
    capture >> bg_frame;

    Mat cur_frame;  // Capture current frame

    double threshold = (double)50;
    while (1) {
        // Capture current frame
        capture >> cur_frame;

        // Loop all pixel in image

        for (int i = 0; i < cur_frame.rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cur_frame.cols; ++j) {
                Vec3b bg_RGB_pixel = bg_frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
                Vec3b cur_RGB_pixel = cur_frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j);

                double pixel_different = sqrt(  pow(bg_RGB_pixel[0], cur_RGB_pixel[0]) + 
                                                pow(bg_RGB_pixel[1], cur_RGB_pixel[1]) + 
                                                pow(bg_RGB_pixel[2], cur_RGB_pixel[2]) );

                if (pixel_different > threshold) {
                    cur_RGB_pixel[0] = 0;
                    cur_RGB_pixel[1] = 0;
                    cur_RGB_pixel[2] = 0;

                    cur_frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = cur_RGB_pixel;
                }
            }
        }
        imshow("Background Subtraction", cur_frame);


        char c = cvWaitKey(10);
        if (c == 27) 
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I get this error.
The error appear at this line

```
Vec3b bg_RGB_pixel = bg_frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for all suggestion and solution.

[Edit]
*exception: std::bad_alloc when using Mat.at(i, j);* - **Solved**
I just found that the problem is about my AntiVirus software which I installed in my computer.
I have to confirm that the application is allowed to use my webcam, but the program still executed and it gets the following error because it capture nothing.

But now, I found new problem with my algorithm. It does not remove the background. The output is just a black screen.

What should I do now?

Comment: Add if(bg_frame.cols == 0) return 0; before your endless loop (or a similar test).

Comment: Try double pixel_different = abs(bg_RGB_pixel[0]-cur_RGB_pixel[0]) + abs(bg_RGB_pixel[1] - cur_RGB_pixel[1]) + abs(bg_RGB_pixel[2]-cur_RGB_pixel[2]) );

                if (pixel_different < threshold) ...

Comment: It's work! Can you explain what's wrong with my code? @Micka

Comment: I have no idea what you have intended with the pow's. Youve calculated sqrt(B_bg^B_img + G_bg^G_img + ...) which doesnt look like estimating a "difference" between the pixels

Comment: I seem Ah... just put the wrong parameter. It should be pow(B1[0] - B2[0], 2). Anyway, thank you for the solution. ;) @Micka

Comment: Version in your comment looks better and should work too! (If you test against < threshold instead of >)

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

I am pretty sure you are not using pow() correctly. I assume you are looking for the power-of-2 of (bg_RGB_pixel[0] - cur_RGB_pixel[0]) etc.  What you have seems to me to do bg_RGB_pixel to the power of cur_RGB_pixel  .

I wrote it in a bit longer form since I think it's clearer (first calculated the diff, then the power; see code below).

Also, I think you want the pixel_different to be LESS than the threshold - not MORE - in order to zero it out the background that does not change relative to the first captured reference frame (unless you want to segment out the NEW stuff on the image).

Anyway - this worked for me (showing only the inner, per image, loop):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cur_frame.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cur_frame.cols; ++j) {
            Vec3b bg_RGB_pixel = bg_frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
            Vec3b cur_RGB_pixel = cur_frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j);

            int diff0 = bg_RGB_pixel[0] - cur_RGB_pixel[0];
            int diff1 = bg_RGB_pixel[1] - cur_RGB_pixel[1];
            int diff2 = bg_RGB_pixel[2] - cur_RGB_pixel[2];

            double pixel_different = sqrt(pow(diff0, 2) + pow(diff1, 2) + pow(diff2, 2));

            if (pixel_different < threshold) {
                cur_RGB_pixel[0] = 0;
                cur_RGB_pixel[1] = 0;
                cur_RGB_pixel[2] = 0;

                cur_frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = cur_RGB_pixel;
            }
        }
    }
```

I got most of the background segmented out, and items that appear in the camera field-of-view after I started, are not segmented out (not blacked-out) and showing in the original color. 
Within reason... even the new items have some parts blacked out. But your are using a very simplistic segmentation algorithm, so this is expected and the results are actually pretty good.

Michael